# How can I host a Jar file on Tomcat

Tags: java, swing

I have developed a simple management software like library,shop item management. when I compiled my java files I get a .Jar file which I want to host somewhere (tomcat etc.) so that anybody can go to that IP and add/modify the iteams. Is it possible ? I developed that software using java Jframe.

Comment: You might want to investigate "web apps"...

Comment: I wonder why people are down voting this question !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a JNLP (Java Network Launch Protocol)

The Java Network Launch Protocol (JNLP) enables an application to be launched on a client desktop by using resources that are hosted on a remote web server

See [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html) for detail about JNLP.

Also you will get a lot of information from google about JNLP.

Comment: See also the [Java Web Start info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) here at SO..